# SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: html, json, syntax-error

I am posting this because I have not seen this exact question before, and I have had no luck going through previous posts.
I am creating a layout of an application called Exhibit, one that lays out my data on a timeline. The html code is structured for Exhibit. 
My data is stored in a JSON file. I have checked this with JLint and it seems to be in the correct format. Yet I am thrown the above error regarding my JSON file.

Here is one object from my JSON file.

```
{

"items" : [
    {
        "url" :        "http:\/\/twitter.com\/acarvin\/statuses\/32815014167445504",
        "uri" :        "file:\/\/\/C:\/Users\/david\/Documents\/Work\/Exhibit\/CAR\/item#%40acarvin%3A%20AlJaz%20showing%20huge%20crowds%20rushing%20down%20a%20Cairo%20street.%20\'It%20is%20an%20intense%20battle%20here.\'%20%23jan25",
        "time" :       "2011-02-02 14:58:03",
        "date" :       "2005",
        "action" :     "reporting",
        "hour" :       "14:58:03",
        "role" :       "reporter",
        "username" :   "acarvin",
        "keywords" :   [
            "crowd",
            " battle",
            " al jazeera"
        ],
        "ignoretime" : "2\/2\/2011 14:58:03",
        "type" :       "Item",
        "label" :      "@acarvin: AlJaz showing huge crowds rushing down a Cairo street. \'It is an intense battle here.\' #jan25",
        "gender" :     "male",
        "location" :   "talaat harb",
        "origin" :     "file:\/\/\/C:\/Users\/david\/Documents\/Work\/Exhibit\/CAR\/hands-on.html#%40acarvin%3A%20AlJaz%20showing%20huge%20crowds%20rushing%20down%20a%20Cairo%20street.%20\'It%20is%20an%20intense%20battle%20here.\'%20%23jan25"
    }
          ]
 }
```

Can anyone see what may be happening?
note: I specified the type of my data as application/json when I called it.

Comment: Your JSON does not contain `)`. Either the JSON you used is different, or the message is not about the syntax of your JSON.

Comment: Although to be fair, sometimes parsers get confused and misreport errors... http://jsonlint.com points to the *beginning* of the strings with the invalid escapes saying it was expecting a string, which isn't as useful as it might be...

Answer (score 0):

There are several invalid escapes in your strings in the form `\'`. While those are valid in JavaScript strings (whether single-quoted or double-quoted), they are not valid JSON. In JSON, a `'` is just a `'`.

With those in place, the string will not validate. With the extraneous `\` removed, it will. (I used http://jsonlint.com to confirm.)